# How to disable IE message for reference information with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to disable IE (browsers) message for reference information with JavaScript?

this is the situation:

I have a form that i submit, after submitting i reload the page and appears the following message :

"To display this page Firefox has to resend information that will repeat previous actions (such as a demand or confirmation of an order)."

i need help...

Thanks

ps: sorry I'm not English :)

Comment: The title of your question references IE (Internet Explorer), but the body of your question references FireFox.  Is your question about FF?

Comment: This message will appear in both IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [POST/Redirect/GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This message appears whenever you reload a page that was received from an HTTP POST.
It appears because HTTP POSTs are intended to be non-repeatable.
For example, if you buy something online, the website will usually send an HTTP POST to its server saying that you spent *X* dollars.  Without that warning, it would be possible for Firefox or IE to automatically reload the page, sending a second HTTP POST.  This would tell the server that you spent *X* dollars a second time, and would make you very angry.  Therefore, the browsers have that warning.

To get rid of it, change your page to an HTTP GET.

For example:

```
<form method="GET">
```

Alternatively, you can keep it an HTTP POST, and have the server send a redirect in response to the POST, telling the browser to send an HTTP GET to a separate page.  This means that you don't have the risk of sending the request twice, as I described above.